# How to indent F# code in Visual Studio 2008 in #light mode

Tags: visual-studio, f#, indentation

Is pressing **spacebar** only way to indent for F# in #light mode?

This seems like a serious hindrance while using #light mode.
Is there a better way than keep on pressing space bar in VS 2008?

[image]

**[Answer]** by Brian ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766662/how-to-indent-f-code-in-visual-studio-2008-in-light-mode/766677#766677))
1. Go to `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> F# -> Tabs`
2. Select Insert Spaces

[image]

Comment: Just a note that all this stuff works right 'out of the box' now, and #light is now the default (no need to put it at the top of files).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See here

http://www.pandamonial.com/2008/04/f-vs-option.html

Comment: Ha! I never knew that there was such an option in visual studio.  Thanks Brian.

Comment: This link current 404's - fix it for a plus 1

Comment: Ah  ignore that the answer was integrated directly into the question - nice archiving work +1